# How to trigger multiple pr jobs at once

Tags: jenkins, plugins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm using build with parameter plugin such that i can given multiple branches.
`let ex: test1 test2 test3` these are my branches
if `test1` trigger `test2` and `test3` are in queue once `test1` build successfully i want to trigger `test2` and `test3` at a time because of dependency how to achieve this please help me to out of this issue

Answer (score 0):

There is Pipeline: Build step plugin. Install it and use in pipeline like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        \\some stages here
        stage ('trigger job 2') {
            steps {
                build 'job_2'
            }
        }
        stage ('trigger job 3') {
            steps {
                build 'job_3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can run triggered jobs in parallel.

```
stage('Parallel Stage') {
        parallel {
            stage('job 2') {
                steps {
                    build 'job_2'
                    }
                }
                stage('job 3') {
                    steps {
                        build 'job_3'
                    }
                }
```